# How to remove the output of Bitblt? (MFC)

Tags: c++, mfc

I have outputted an image (bitmap) which is created by `Bitblt`.

Now I want to get rid of it. How can I do? (Do not use the **patch**, like `FillSolidRect`, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to "undo" or "erase" a BitBlt or any other drawing output (except in *very* special cases where you do XOR-based drawing, which you can undo by doing another XOR drawing operation on top of the original).

The only thing you can do is to draw on something else on top of it, which is what you are calling a "patch". Typically, you would draw a solid rectangle of the window's background color. This is precisely what the `OnEraseBkgrnd` message handler does by default, which runs just before `OnPaint`. Specifically, it uses your window class's background brush, which is typically a brush that draws using the `COLOR_3DFACE` (for a dialog) or `COLOR_WINDOW` (for a window) system color.

Of course, you could always just *not* do the BitBlt in the first place. *All* painting code should *always* go inside of the `OnPaint` message handler function, so there is no way that you could end up with "stale" graphics. Whenever the window needs repainting, it is going to call this function, and your code inside of that function will repaint the window. If you don't want it to be painted with a bitmap, don't call BitBlt.

If you've done a BitBlt on top of your window using a temporary `CDC` object (which you generally should *not* be doing), you can force this to be erased by triggering a repaint of the window. The easiest way is to use the window's `InvalidateRect()` member function; passing `NULL` as the pointer to the rectangle to be invalidated will invalidate the window's entire client area, or you can just invalidate the area that you blitted.